# php http request adding random hex code to body

Tags: php, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I have a CSV export on my web system and am trying to query this from a client. I have never had any issues, but for some reason, for one of my clients, the returned data has an extra 4 characters just before the body that I cannot work out where it's coming from!

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 09:17:22 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2
Set-Cookie: username=xxx expires=Mon, 17-Jun-2013 11:17:22 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: password=xxx; expires=Mon, 17-Jun-2013 11:17:22 GMT; path=/
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="xxx-Stock.csv"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/csv

20b1
"code","dsc","cat","sub","whqc","qty"
..................
```

In the above, the 20b1 is going before my body. I've downloaded the file manually through the same means and cannot see it in the file.

```
The export code looks like:
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");
header("Content-type: text/csv");
$tmp["header"] = "\"code\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"dsc\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"cat\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"sub\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"whqc\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"qty\"\n";
echo $tmp["header"];

for ($i = 1; $i <= $data["count"]; $i++ ) {
  $j = 1;
  while ( isset($data[$i][$j]) ) {
    $tmp["line"] = "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["code"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["full_name"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["prstkcat"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["prsubcat"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i][$j]["whqc"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i][$j]["qty"]) . "\"\n";
    echo $tmp["line"];
    $j++;
  }
}
```

Weird thing is, it doesn't happen for my other clients, so I'm thinking perhaps there is something weird in the data coming from this client. If I comment out some of the `$tmp["line"]`, it doesn't show it. Other times, if i comment out one of the lines, this code changes.

What on earth could be putting this character in there?!

Update:
It only did this when the server returned chunked encoding. I changed the code to the following and it works now (would love an explanation as this is not my area of expertise!).

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");
header("Content-type: text/csv");

$tmp["header"] = "\"code\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"dsc\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"cat\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"sub\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"whqc\",";
$tmp["header"].= "\"qty\"\n";
$tmp["line"] = "";
for ($i = 1; $i <= $data["count"]; $i++ ) {
  $j = 1;
  while ( isset($data[$i][$j]) ) {
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["code"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["full_name"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["prstkcat"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i]["prsubcat"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i][$j]["whqc"]) . "\",";
    $tmp["line"].= "\"" .  str_replace("\"", "\"\"", $data[$i][$j]["qty"]) . "\"\n";
    $j++;
  }
}
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($tmp["header"] . $tmp["line"]));
echo $tmp["header"] . $tmp["line"];
```

Comment: Hmm, that Hex code(s) results in ` +` when converted back to characters - It's a strange one for sure. What do you have before those header calls?

Comment: That's the chunk encoding control sequence.

Comment: So would that be coming out with my output?

Comment: So I just commented out the second $tmp["line"] and now the code it puts in is `2075` which is a 'U'. Dunno what is going on! I might try run the same code on my local machine and see what I get.

Comment: Perhaps it's some kind of content length been output from somewhere.

Comment: OK not sure why but it had to do with chunked encoding. See my original question for what I changed. Weird!!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove this one

```
echo $tmp["header"];
```